# jboss 6.1 PermGen space

Tags: jboss, java-6, eclipse-kepler

> I have uploaded PermGen size in run.conf.bat but still showing problem
>   while running my project.

I have changed the permGen Sapce as:JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
    Error:

> Unexpected error during load of:jxl.read.biff.FormulaRecord:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975567/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-and-java-lang-classnotfoundexception

Comment: and this too [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230746/optimizing-xms-xmx-xxmaxpermsize-in-jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230746/optimizing-xms-xmx-xxmaxpermsize-in-jvm)