# Unreachable objects are not garbage collected from heap

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I'am struggling with unreachable objects in my JVM heap (Java 1.7). As you can see from the picture (all classes on the picture are unreachable), we have more than 74 % objects with no reference, so It should be garbagged collected. This state becomes after 3 weeks uptime on our tomcat 7 server where run only Probe monitoring app, tomcat manager and our webapp which is probably source of the problem.

Our application is based on JSF 1.2 with state saving on client which is what you see in picture below - char arrays with ViewSaveState mostly.
When I manually run GC from jVisualVM It removes all unreachable objects and everything is ok until 3 weeks when the heap reaches its limit.

How is it possible that some objects aren't cleaned up?

**Our JVM params**

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=29001
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
-Xms320m
-Xmx2500m
-XX:MaxPermSize=500m
-XX:PermSize=96m
-verbose:gc
-Xloggc:/var/log/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

[image: http://puu.sh/b7mjB/3d23de7d41.png]

**STACKTRACES for OutOfMemoryError**

I think that cause is hidden somewhere else, stacktraces came from different part of app. There could be some leak, but stacktraces report only last component which claims some memory in time when there isn't any.

```
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
            at java.util.LinkedHashMap.createEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:442)
            at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:888)
            at java.util.LinkedHashMap.addEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:427)
            at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:509)
            at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookup(OpenListResourceBundle.java:134)
            at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookupTablesIfNecessary(OpenListResourceBundle.java:113)
            at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(OpenListResourceBundle.java:74)
            at sun.util.resources.TimeZoneNamesBundle.handleGetObject(TimeZoneNamesBundle.java:75)
            at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:389)
            at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:392)
------------------
Exception in thread "Timer-22" Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
------------------
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1468)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
         at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
        ... 74 more
--------------
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:350)
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:137)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:173)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:443)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.a.a(a.java:632)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.a.a(a.java:355)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.e(fc.java:682)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.k(fc.java:1481)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getTimestampX(ResultSet.java:1075)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getTimestamp(ResultSet.java:1034)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the heap reaches its limit"? Do you get an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Did you see error messages like "promotion failure" or "concurrent mode failure" in gc logs? BTW how about the load on your server? Generally ~2.5G of heap space is very less for servers.

Comment: We have quite small app which takes only just 400MB from heap on first run only if there are 10 concurrent users and that not happens much often. So there should be 2GB reserve, moreover we use 2 nodes so there should by plenty of free memory. I didn't find any mentioned error in gc.log.

Comment: How frequently CMS GC is happening? Is it freeing some memory at least? If you share your GC logs, I can take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found out that I have all logs mixed in catalina.out for last half year, so there is no possible way how to distribute gc log. To this directory /var/log/gc.log it wasn't write permission.

Comment: Can you paste the full OOM message. It can be related to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded. g1 gc might help.

Comment: I edited my question, I didn't find such error in our logs from attached question. Also, our cpu is loaded no more than 10% most of the time.

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is that you are overloading the JVM with pathological behavior in `finalize()` methods. If you have classes that override `Object.finalize()` the JVM has to do a surprising amount of work in order to actually clean them up (and, in turn, clean up all their referenced objects). If you create such objects faster than the garbage collector can process them you'll quickly run into trouble.

This article walks through a [pathological finalizer example](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml) in detail, but to summarize:

1. An object with a `finalize()` method falls out of scope and (conceptually) becomes eligible for GC.
2. Unlike a normal object which can simply be freed, the JVM holds a special reference to the object via a [`Finalizer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java), preventing these objects from being trivially collected. Even short-lived objects survive the initial GC and move into longer-lived sections of the heap if associated with a `finalize()`.
3. Now these objects will be processed by the dedicated `Finalizer` thread, which will call `.finalize()` on each object in turn. Objects that haven't yet had their turn remain on the heap though they're unreachable.
4. Once the object is processed by the `Finalizer` thread this last reference is removed and the object can finally actually be GC'ed. Since the object survived one or more collection rounds it may take some time for the GC to get around to it.
5. Any objects the finalizable object referenced in turn are only now eligible for collection.

If your `.finalize()` methods take a particularly long time or if you're creating a large number of such objects the `Finalizer` thread can't keep up with the demand and objects will continue to queue up, eventually filling your entire heap.

There are other possible explanations, but over-use of `finalize()` is a likely reason. [Effective Java Item 7 strongly discourages finalizers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7):

> **Finalizers are unpredictable, often dangerous, and generally unnecessary.** Their use can cause erratic behavior, poor performance, and portability problems....
>
> Providing a finalizer for a class can, under rare conditions, arbitrarily delay reclamation of its instances.

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects in the behaviour you are facing. First and foremost, having unreachable objects inside heap at any given time is perfectly normal. Garbage Collection will clean the unreachable objects during the next run and will clean the heap from them. So, seeing unreachable data structures in heap dump is not evil nor abnormal.

But when facing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error, these unreachable references should have been cleaned. You can check this via adding *-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError* to your startup parameters, triggering heap dump on next OutOfMemoryError generated. When you now crawl this dump, you should not see the unreachable objects, at least not of any significant size.

After understanding this, the underlying problem is still unclear, one of the possible causes can definitely be a heap leak. For this, you can either try to go ahead with the same memory dump gotten during the JVM crash with OutOfMemoryError, or you can make your life easier and attach  a Java memory leak detector to find the exact location of the leak in your source code.

Comment: `For this, you can either try to go ahead with the same memory dump gotten` -> No,  Unreachable objects implies you can't see the GC root info. One can compare the heaps, not find the exact leak.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be related to this one

[Java heap overwhelmed by unreachable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370738/java-heap-overwhelmed-by-unreachable-objects)

I found it as I'm facing the same problem in an IBM JVM 5 runninf on AIX 6.1

The only amount of retained heap that grows consistently between two fullgcs is the unreachable objects, marked, if I'm not wrong, with ROOT as the dominator in Eclipse MAT.

To get these dumps, I configureg the JVM to create a sysdump after a fullgc using the Xdump option (only for IBM JVMs, I think)

Hope this helps, and if anybody knows if the GC verbose log leaves a trace of the unreachable objects that couldn't be cleaned, please let me know!

Carlos