# frequent gc pauses - how to debug/profiling

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have a application, which is doing frequent gc pauses(mostly young gen)[young gen has UseParNewGC]. Please suggest how to go about to debug the issue.
jVisualVM, gcViewer,Jrpofiler,jmap - which can help best or a combination of these.
Env:
Windows Server 2003
JDK 1.6

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give any suggestions without more details. Every GC issue is specific.

But, you should start with : [Is there a cookbook guide for GC problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6871213/772000)

Answer (score 1):

High frequent NewGen Collections are caused by a high allocation rate. VisualGC ("Sampler") should be sufficient to track down which classes are allocated most. A possibility to reduce newgen frequency is, to increase Eden size like described in e.g. [here](http://java-is-the-new-c.blogspot.de/2013/07/tuning-and-benchmarking-java-7s-garbage.html)